# Should both ground and neutral in an electrical subpanel be bonded to the service ground?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, grounding-and-bonding

I put in a 100 AMP sub panel from a 200 AMP service. The neutral and ground are separated in the sub panel. Would this bond the sub panel to the ground and neutral coming from service ground wire? I used 2-2-2-4 wire.

Comment: The neutral and ground bars should be separated from each other but there should be a way to ground the actual subpanel box. Usually there is a little metal bar connected to the case that you can screw into the ground bar

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a 100 amp Sub-panel coming off of a 200 amp Main-panel.  Note the errors to current NEC code.  Since there was an upgrade to the system, this one needed to be upgraded to current standards.

The ground had been connected to the neutral lug and the ground stake had also been connected to same.  Also, note the horizontal bus connector bar.

(Believe it or not, the local electrical inspector missed this during remodeling with added circuits.)

[image: Incorrect Sub-Panel Grounding]

This shows the corrected connections in the same panel.

[image: Correct Sub-Panel Grounding]

This is the removed bar:

[image: Removed bar]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be properly bonded and grounded.

Make sure you do NOT install the (green) bond screw (or strap) in the sub-panel.

Both the ground and neutral will terminate in the main panel on the neutral/ground bar. These two wires serve two distinctly different purposes once they leave the main panel.